# how to solve max-height problem in CSS while using overflow scroll for different screen heights (mobile)?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, overflow

I need to use overflow scroll CSS property on a div to make it scrollable, but just realised to make it work i've to use either max-height or height property.

> [In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

But the problem is when i set a max-height/height considering one mobile screen it doesn't create the same expected view for other screen (i want the text to occupy whole mobile screen and then overflow)

I'm kinda newbie and trying to learn, Can anyone please help??

Comment: Try using 100vh (viewport height) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Answer (score 0):

As Jakob E mentioned in his comment, `height: 100vh;` should work in modern browsers.

You could also use a percentage for height to make it relative its container so something like `height: 100%;` should work too.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for reply, calculating height dynamically worked for me.
=> overflow: auto; max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);

actually i had some header of 200px above the target div

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replying.

Calculating the height dynamically worked for me. Here's the code

```
 overflow: auto;
 max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
```

(sorry actually i had some header of 200px above the target div, that's why - 200px)